# How can I route some emails to a script in Postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, regex

How do I route all emails directed to user-*@example.com (i.e. user-1234@example.com) to a pipe command in Postfix? The idea is to create craigslist-style anonymization by assigning dynamic email aliases to each user. I can't seem to find relevant information in the documentation, however.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay. And now a different approach.

Put a new transport in `master.cf`:

```
coolscript unix -    n    n    -    50    pipe
    flags=R user=vmail argv=/path/to/script -o SENDER=${sender} -m USER=${user} EXTENSION=${extension}
```

you can extend/modify the parameters as you like.

Then (to eliminate pcre) you can use regexp to do the "catch-thing" in `main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/redirect.regexp
```

And in `/etc/postfix/redirect.regexp` you put:

```
/^user-.*@example\.com/   coolscript:
```

Reload Postfix with `postfix reload`.

Comment: if I put /example.com/ it'll work and my data gets recorded, if I put /^user-.*@example.com/ it'll get a relay access denied, any idea why? I already have relay_domains=$mydestination, $transport_maps but apparently that doesnt solve the problem

Comment: @ChristopherThomas You did not escape the dot in example.com?!

Comment: oops, good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First check if you have pcre compiled into Posfix with `postconf -m`. Then you can set in `main.cf`:

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/redirect.pcre
```

and in `/etc/postfix/redirect.pcre` you put:

```
/^user-.*@example\.com$/   somelocalalias
```

and in `/etc/aliases` you add

```
somelocalalias: |"/path/to/script"
```

Don't forget to `postalias /etc/aliases` and afterwards reload Postfix with `postfix reload`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're suggesting pcre over regexp? Also, shouldn't I be specifying the pipe in master.cf?

Comment: @If you know the answer why ask? Sure there are more ways to achieve the same. If you prefer regexp then go for it. Even transports in master.cf can do it if you watch out for chroot pitfalls.

Comment: This was the magic I needed to make my script work. Transport wasn't working for some reason, this worked first time.

Comment: Under which user is the script from `/etc/aliases` run?